# "tail -f <file>" piped to "grep -m1" is not exiting on first match

Tags: bash, grep

Say I have this file content:

```
  1 lots
  2 of
  3 content
  4 above
  5
  6 My match string
  7 =======================
  8
  9 other
 10 content
 11 below
```

I want line number of "My match string".

There are some facts:
(1). Match string occurs only once in the file.
(2). File may not exist when running my script.
(3). The file may be really huge that it's generation takes time, and this line gets written only after a few seconds after generation.

My bash script MUST contain a command to generate file followed by finding the above mentioned line number:

My script looks like this:

```
<command to generate file>
if file exists 
    tail -f -n +1 my_log_file | grep "My match string" -nm1
```

For big files which take time for generation, this command works.
tail -f keeps piping content to grep and once this match string gets written to file, -m1 makes grep exit successfully (i.e on first match).

But for small files, grep matches correctly and prints the match, but doesn't come out till I press ctrl+c

Why is this difference in behavior, any idea how fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the useless `tail`.

What happens is that

- `grep` exists as it should, but
- `tail -f` won't exit until it tries to write something to the pipe and notices that there is nobody reading from it.

Comment: As the file is getting generated and written into on the fly, tail -f is the best option for me.Is there any possible alternate?

Comment: Maybe help `tail` by making sure there is sufficient data? For example, write a header to the log file? And you should really ask this question on [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: In case we know the max upper limit, i see that
timeout 2 tail -f -n+1 build-psf.sh | grep -m1 "Copy content for packaging"

Comment: This just ensures that the command doesn't hang for ever, by keeping the timeout limit.